# Vertical spacing after a tabu environment

Tags: tables, tabu

When creating a tabu with two rows, I get more vertical spacing after the environment than when I create a tabu with only one row.

In the document below, the first tabu has two lines, and there is a small space between the end of the table and the rule below it. In the second tabu, I only have one line, and there is a larger space below it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}

\geometry{a4paper} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X X}%
    These are words & in the first line \\%
    These are more words & in the second line%
\end{tabu}\par%
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par%
%
%
\vspace{2em}\par%
%
%
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X X}%
    These are words & in the first line%
\end{tabu}\par%
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par%
%
\end{document}
```

[image: typeset output of above document, displaying inconsistency in spacing after a tabu environment]

I've been quite careful (I think) with whitespace around the tabu, and I see no difference in the two tables aside from the different number of lines.

I know that I could fix this by adding a `\vspace{0.5em}` or similar right after the tabu with the small spacing, but I am using the tables in a custom command and I would like to avoid a hard-coded solution like this if possible.

*This problem also comes up if I substitute a tabular for the tabu*. Adding `\tabulinesep=Xem` fixes (or appears to fix) the problem for large X (>1em), but I need small spacings (ideally, ~0em).

Any ideas?

Comment: Read the readme here: https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/.

Comment: The same issue is found with the tabular package; it is not unique to tabu

Comment: then better make a tabular example. I never try to debug tabu.

Comment: Do you recommend an edit or a new question?

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with `tabu`, nor with `tabular` or similar environments.

We can replicate the “issue” with `\parbox`. In the code below, the red lines produced by `\test` show where TeX thinks the base line is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\test}{\textcolor{red}{\llap{\smash{\rule{12pt}{0.4pt}}}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\test \parbox{4cm}{One liner xyz}\par
\test \rule{4cm}{0.4pt}

\bigskip

\test \parbox{4cm}{First line \\ second line xyz}\par
\test \rule{4cm}{0.4pt}

\bigskip

\test \parbox{4cm}{First line \\ second line \\ third line xyz}\par
\test \rule{4cm}{0.4pt}

\bigskip

\test \parbox[b]{4cm}{First line \\ second line xyz}\par
\test \rule{4cm}{0.4pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, when we have two or more lines the `\parbox` is (almost) centered with respect to the base line (actually, shifted up a bit). The next paragraph only has a rule, which has very small height, so when TeX does its usual calculations, it finds that in the “two line” case the normal distance between base lines can be preserved; in the “three line” case, the depth of the `\parbox` is very large, so `\lineskip` glue is inserted.

If you instead choose the `[b]` option (which is available also for the `tabular`-like environments), the distance between the base lines is the standard.

So it's not the “space below `tabu`” that changes.